# Can I validate that models are in sync with database schema?

Tags: sequelize.js

Is it possible to validate that all Models can be read/inserted without modifying the DB? `sync()` doesn't seem to do this.

My goal is to implement a simple (read: non-migrations-based) check as part of a continuous deployment workflow that a commit won't break compatibility with the live staging or production databases.